# Wrapping a simple library using Cython

Tags: c++, cython, external, libraries

I am trying to wrap a C library using Cython, since Pybind11 throws me an error on MacOS.

My library consists of the two files

**addon.h:**

```
#ifndef ADDON_H
#define ADDON_H

#include <string>

std::string get_message();

#endif
```

and **addon.cpp:**

```
#include "addon.h"

std::string get_message(){
    return "It worked!! Yay!";
}
```

Using the official Cython tutorial on [Using C libraries](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html), I created the following files in the same directory:

**caddon.pxd:**

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "addon.h":
    string get_message()
```

**addon.pyx:**

```
cimport caddon
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef string caddon.get_message()
```

and **setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("addon", ["addon.pyx"])])
)
```

From running `python3 setup.py build_ext -i` in the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
/Users/macos_user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /Users/macos_user/Desktop/Skripte/cpp/cython/Tut_online/Tut_Libraries/addon.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport caddon
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef string caddon.get_message()                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

addon.pyx:4:18: Syntax error in C variable declaration
Compiling addon.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing addon.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("addon", ["addon.pyx"])])
  File "/Users/macos_user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1112, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/Users/macos_user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1235, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: addon.pyx
```

I don't understand the error source as the C++ Module itself compiles perfectly fine, so there should not be an error in a C variable... It can be used easily using a C++ main `main.cpp` or using Pybind11.

Can someone tell me, where my error is?

I tried to stay as close to the [described tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) and tried to google the error, but other StackOverflow do not seem applicable for my problem.

Comment: This is not a C library but a C++ library. That is where your issues start. You need to tell Cython that this is C++ code.